# How to get MIME content via REST from on-premises Exchange Server

Tags: outlook-web-addins, outlook-restapi

We are trying to get the MIME content of the message via REST as an alternative to EWS.  This approach works against Office 365, but not against ON-PREMISES Exchange Servers that have exposed a preview REST end-point.  I presume this is a limitation, but wanted to check if so.

Get MIME content of a message:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-get-mime-message

Approach to get MIME content is to put '$value' at the end of URL:
https://{on-prem-server}/api/v2.0/me/messages/{id}/$value

Method Not Allowed --- https://{on-prem-exchange-server}/api/v2.0/me/messages/.../$value

Not Found --- https://{on-prem-exchange-server}/api/v1.0/me/messages/.../$value

Comment: Hi,
I try to do the same thing and didn't find an answer.
I also found that if you want to use the api you have to use /{id} instead of /me as it is not supported for hybrid (sorry I didn't find where I read this). I will ask in the form hopping an answer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/116610/mime-content-from-graph-api-for-hybrid-account.html